# Does google crawl and rank content in an amp-list?

Tags: seo, google, amp

I'm building an AMP page. I want to use amp-list and dynamically fetch content for the list from a json endpoint. So if I have a series of products on my home page in an amp-list, will google list the page when users search for those products?